# Render Joomla messages inside a template

Tags: templates, error-reporting

I would like to render Joomla messages inside a component Template because the index.php doesn't fit my needs.

So how do I simulate `<jdoc:include type="message" />` inside `/templates/<tmpl>/html/com_content/article/default.php` for example.

Answer (score 5):

You could also override the default layout for system messages.

To do so, copy the following file:

> ROOT/layouts/joomla/system/message.php

to:

> ROOT/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/layouts/joomla/system/message.php

#### Update:

You can also use Joomla's `loadRenderer` function in the component view.

In the view file, add the following:

```
$document  = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer  = $document->loadRenderer('message');
```

Then for a test, add the following to enqueue a message in the session:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->enqueueMessage('test message');
```

Then anywhere in your view, add the following to output the message:

```
$renderer->render('message');
```

Comment: Sorry it's not the question how to change the layout of the messages. The question is where to output the html code with the message.

Comment: @HaraldLeithner - My bad, didn't read the question properly. I've updated the answer

Comment: much better thc

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use JDocument::getBuffer('message');

in html/com_content/article/default.php

```
<?php
echo $this->document->getBuffer('message')
?>
```

This will also clear the message buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Errors, warnings and notices can be displayed from any component, module, plugin or template using the methods outlined below.

```
// Get a handle to the Joomla! application object
$application = JFactory::getApplication();

// Add a message to the message queue
$application->enqueueMessage(JText::_('SOME_ERROR_OCCURRED'), 'error');

/** Alternatively you may use chaining */
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('SOME_ERROR_OCCURRED'), 'error');
```

Know more from https://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices